# Relaciones de mi base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mariadb

Tengo una duda en cuanto a que 3 tablas haría practicamente lo mismo, Guardar las urls de donde se encuentran los archivos

Tengo una tabla llamada Grupos - Donde se pueden guardar archivos, en general solo es subir archivos. Y ya en su respectivo grupo.(Ya lo hace)

```
Grupo -  Archivos
```

Entonces en el mismo Grupo. Hay una sección de tareas

```
Simulando un Classroom
```

En dicho grupo : una Tarea es publicada por un profesor  Entonces

El sube la tarea, pero también sube Archivos.

Entonces tendría otra tabla llamada

```
 Tareas - ArchivosTareas
```

Entonces, cuando un alumno quiere subir sus tareas, También necesita subir archivos.. de  cuya tarea. que quedaría así

```
Entrega - ArchivosEntrega
```

Entonces ahí es donde tengo duda en cuanto a usar esa forma la relación, Ya que no sé si esto sea optimo. por lo mismo de repetir tablas con el mismo objetivo de guardar archivos.

Este es mi Diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explico mi relaciones:

un usuario puede crear grupos, por eso en la tabla  grupo, hay un campo que dice quien creo cuya sala.

Entonces otro usuario, Se puede inscribir a dicho grupo, por eso esta la tabla pivot.
Para hacer la relacion de que un usuario puede estar inscrito a   varios grupos

Entonces donde dice grupo,  puede tener muchas tareas, y tambien puede tener muchos archivos

en la tabla de tareas, puede hbaer muchos archivosTareas que subió un profesor. Para que descargue el material

Entonces en archivos, La relación va hacía usuarios, para decir que un usuario puede  subir varios archivos.

eso es lo más revelante por si  surgía una duda.
porque lo demás es como lo mencione, no sé si tenga que hacer 3 tablas para cada uno de los archivos .

¡No se si esto esta bien hecho, o que haya una mejor manera de hacerlo!

Ya que en eloquent

la manera de acceder a ellos es muy fácil. bueno   hasta cierto punto.

**Ignorar los datos que aún hacen falta a mis tablas en cuanto . solo necesito comprender las relaciones de ellas mismas**

Answer (score 0):

Tener una tabla por cada "tipo" sabiendo que su estructura interna es la misma, es síntoma de mala normalización ya que te estas saltando la 1FN y 2FN, las cuales evitan la redundancia y crean inconsistencia en los datos y en el modelo. Deberías tener una sola tabla tabla llamada "archivos" (en ingles y en minúscula es mejor: files) y añadir una columna que indica el role que lo ha subido "role_id", luego tendrás una tabla de roles que indica si el usuario (user_id) es profesor y/o alumno (role_id) ya que puede tener los dos.

[image: MER]